# SQL select statement inside a select to remove duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a data table where a person can belong to more than one group; however, I want to pull the group with the most recent date.  A person's group could have been changed at some point.

```
ID     Name            Group         Date
2      Smith, Jane       B        2021-02-12
2      Smith, Jane       D        2021-10-29
5      Bower, Carl       A        2021-05-01
8      Hart, Mary        A        2004-04-04
8      Hart, Mary        B        2021-09-03
```

Smith and Hart are repeats, but retrieving the most recent date would give the desired result:

```
2      Smith, Jane       D        2021-10-29
5      Bower, Carl       A        2021-05-01
8      Hart, Mary        B        2021-09-03
```

Here is what I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name, Group, MAX(Date) as Date
FROM table_d 
WHERE Date >= '20210101'
GROUP BY Name, Group
ORDER BY Name;
```

but this is still giving me all groups

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. Also, combining SELECT DISTINCT with GROUP BY raises many eyebrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the specific database but in typical SQL you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the rows you want. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as rn
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: the actual table is 40,000 rows long...

Comment: A table with 40k rows is nowadays a very small table. The query should work quite well with it. If you still have performance issues, you can add an index on (`id`, `date`).

Answer (score 0):

using function `year(date) = year(getdate())` solved my problem.

Comment: I refuse to see how your solution relates to your question. Had you asked "how to retrieve current year events", then yes, that would be the solution. Well, ask again on January, 1st 2022 then :)